# Ubuntu 22.04. Upgrading installs new linux-headers, etc. Are they necessary?

Tags: apt, upgrade, 22.04

I tried `sudo apt update` it said there are something to upgrade, so I tried `upgrade`, and the output is below. It says that the following NEW packages will be installed and will use additional 560MB. If they are "new" not "upgrading" as they say, why does it want to install new packages, when I just want to update the system?

```
$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-5.15.0-30 linux-headers-5.15.0-30-generic
  linux-image-5.15.0-30-generic linux-modules-5.15.0-30-generic
  linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-30-generic
The following packages will be upgraded:
  apport libldap-2.5-0 libldap-common libpcre3 libssl3 libxml2 linux-firmware
  linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic needrestart openssl
  python3-apport python3-problem-report python3-software-properties
  software-properties-common
16 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 351 MB/352 MB of archives.
After this operation, 559 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The currently installed packages `linux-generic`, `linux-headers-generic`, etc. are being upgraded.

Part of that upgrade involves installing a new version of the kernel.  The packages with names like `linux-image-5.15.0-30-generic` go with the new version of the kernel.

Comment: Why does it take so much space? If it is installing new kernel, can I delete old kernel to save space?

Comment: It is advisable to always keep one old kernel installed along with the newest one. That way, if a new kernel causes problems, you can revert back to the old one. Once you have three kernels installed, you can do `sudo apt autoremove` and it will remove the oldest one.